# What are types of coalgebras that are more naturally described by cooperads?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, coalgebras, operads

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a symmetric monoidal category. An object $X \in \mathsf{C}$ has two operads "naturally" (the two constructions aren't functorial) associated to it: the operad of endomorphisms and the operad of coendomorphisms
$$\mathtt{End}_X(r) = \operatorname{Mor}(X^{\otimes r}, X), \; \mathtt{coEnd}_X(r) = \operatorname{Mor}(X, X^{\otimes r}).$$

An algebra over an operad $\mathtt{P}$ is then a morphism $\mathtt{P} \to \mathtt{End}_X$, and a coalgebra over $\mathtt{P}$ is a morphism $\mathtt{P} \to \mathtt{coEnd}_X$. If one likes, everything can be done in the enriched setting, e.g. dg-modules over a field, and a coalgebra structure on $X$ is equivalent to coactions:
$$\mathtt{P}(r) \otimes X \to X^{\otimes r}$$
that satisfy associativity, equivariance, unitality... relations.

Often, one hears that "coalgebras are encoded by cooperads". The definition of cooperads is formally dual to the definition of operads, and a coalgebra over a cooperad $\mathtt{C}$ is given by morphisms
$$X \to \mathtt{C}(r) \otimes^{\Sigma_r} X^{\otimes r}$$
satisfying relations formally dual to the relations defining an algebra over an operad.

But it seems to me that, in algebra at least, most notions of coalgebras encountered in nature are more naturally seen as coalgebras over operads, rather than coalgebras over cooperads. For example, a coassociative coalgebra is more naturally seen as an operator $\Delta : C \to C \otimes C$ (so, something like $\mathtt{Ass}(2) \otimes C \to C \otimes C$), rather than a map $C \to \mathtt{Ass}^*(2) \otimes C \otimes C$.

I think it's even more evident with e.g. Poisson coalgebras. IMO it's natural to think there's a cobracket and a coproduct both acting on $C$ (so, something like $\mathtt{Poiss}(2) \otimes C \to C \otimes C$ mapping $\mu \otimes x$ to the coproduct $\Delta(x)$ of $x$ and $\lambda \otimes x$ to the cobracket $\delta(x)$). But it's not natural at all (IMO) to think of a coaction that maps $x$ to $\mu^* \otimes \Delta(x) + \lambda^* \otimes \delta(x) \in \mathtt{Poiss}^*(2) \otimes^{\Sigma_2} (C \otimes C)$: everything is jumbled together.

Of course, when one deals with finite-type dg-modules over a field of characteristic zero, everything can be dualized and there's no difference (AFAIK) between coalgebras over $\mathtt{P}$ and coalgebras over $\mathtt{P}^*$. But still, are there examples of coalgebra types that are more naturally given by cooperads? And what about topological operads, say, where things cannot be dualized as easily?

Comment: [Re-asked on MO.](http://mathoverflow.net/q/239815/36146)